# What is the negation of the statement "y is a composite number smaller than two"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I am wondering what the negation of the statement: "$y$ is a composite number smaller than two" would be. Would it be:

1) $y$ is a composite number greater than or equal to two

or is it,

2) $y$ is a non-composite (prime) number greater than or equal to two?

Thanks.

Comment: $\neg( A \land B) = \neg A \lor \neg B$.

Comment: There is a subtle difference between a "syntactical" and a "semantical" negation in this case. By De Morgan's law stated above the synctatical negation is "*$y$ is $\geq 2$ or it is a prime number*". But if it is clear that $y$ ranges among the positive integers, since there is no composite number smaller than $2$, a semantical negation may be *a rose is a rose* or any tautology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negation is formed by simply inserting not:

> y is **not** a composite number smaller than two

You're probably asking how to  apply [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to this new statement, in which case you're looking for

> y is not a composite number OR y is not smaller than two

Comment: Even safer is prepending “It is not the case that,” so the negation (same in this case) would be “It is not the case that $y$ is a composite number smaller than $2$.” Observing that the original statement, “$y$ is a composite number smaller than two” means “$y$ is a composite number and $y$ is smaller than two,” the negation can be worked out with rules of propositional logic and becomes “Either $y$ is not a composite number or $y$ is not smaller than two.”

Answer (score 2):

Either y is not a composite number or y is not smaller than 2

Answer (score 1):

You should think in sets. Let $A$ be the set such that y is composite and smaller than two. $A^c$, which is the negation of $A$, is the set such that $y$ isn't composite or $y\ge 2$.